# Find the shortest paths between connected nodes (csv files)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, jupyter-notebook, networkx, edges

I'm trying to find the longest shortest path(s) between 2 counties. I was given 2 .txt files, one with all of the nodes (county ID, population, latitude and longitude, and commuters inside the county) and one with the links (source county, destination county, distance, number of commuters).

```
01001 43671 32.523283 -86.577176 7871
01003 140415 30.592781 -87.748260 45208
01005 29038 31.856515 -85.331312 8370
01007 20826 33.040054 -87.123243 3199
01009 51024 33.978461 -86.554768 8966
01011 11714 32.098285 -85.704915 2237
01013 21399 31.735884 -86.662232 5708
01015 112249 33.741989 -85.817544 39856
01017 36583 32.891233 -85.288745 9281
01019 23988 34.184158 -85.621930 4645
01021 39593 32.852554 -86.689982 8115
01023 15922 32.027681 -88.257855 3472
01025 27867 31.688155 -87.834164 7705
...
```

```
01001 01001 0 7871
01001 01007 76.8615966430995 7
01001 01013 87.9182871130127 37
01001 01015 152.858742124667 5
01001 01021 38.1039665382023 350
01001 01031 140.051395101308 8
01001 01037 57.6726084645634 12
01001 01047 48.517875245493 585
01001 01051 38.9559472915165 741
01001 01053 169.524277177911 5
01001 01059 245.323879285783 7
01001 01065 102.775324022097 2
01001 01073 114.124721221283 142
...
01003 48439 932.019063970525 9
01003 53033 3478.13978129133 11
01003 54081 997.783781484149 10
01005 01005 0.000134258785931453 8370
01005 01011 44.3219329413987 72
01005 01021 168.973302699063 7
...
```

The first file with the nodes is called "THE_NODES.txt" and the second is "THE_LINKS.txt". 
How would I use python code to find the longest shortest path(s) between any of the two counties? I assume I start with making a graph of the network, and since the second file has the connections, use 'THE_LINKS.txt' for the edges(I don't know if the weights would be the distance?)? Also, I think these files can only be read as a csv (correct me if I'm wrong), so I can't (or don't know how to) use networkx for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the read_table function with `|` separator to read .txt files

```py
node = pd.read_table('node.txt', sep='|', header=None)
links = pd.read_table('links.txt', sep='|', header=None)
```

Then you need to find the location of countries ( please refer this link : [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/10077354) ). Then you have to calculate the distance between the countries.

What have you tried so far ? Include that too.

Comment: The location of the countries is in the first file, and the distances are in the second. My question is, how do I use that data to find the shortest path lengths?